# Azure Blue/Green deployment - use same public IP across Load Balancers

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-virtual-machine, azure-load-balancer, azure-traffic-manager

I'm currently using the standard blue/green deployment setup here:

[image]

I need to use the same public IP for both Load Balancers.

Currently it appears that a load balancer (LB) can only use a 'not used' frontend IP configuration. So, I could switch the load balancer off the public IP onto a temporary one then assign the public IP to the other LB. Not such a slick blue/green deployment though.

Is there a way to overcome this issue so I can switch the traffic manager over and the public IP remains the same?

Comment: Big thanks the person who downvoted the question. Not even a comment left as to why.

Comment: maybe you should add a bit more detail on what you are actually trying to achieve? And what traffic are we talking about? HTTP?

Comment: Hmmm, i would have thought this was pretty clear: Is there a way to overcome this issue so I can switch the traffic manager over and the public IP remains the same?

Comment: why dont you just keep using the same LB and just have two different backend pools (blue and green) and then switch over the pool in your LB rule?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/load-balancer/load-balancers/swap-public-ip-addresses

```json
{
  "frontendIPConfigurations": [
    {
      "id": "/subscriptions/subid/resourceGroups/rg1/providers/Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/lb1/frontendIPConfigurations/lbfe1",
      "properties": {
        "publicIPAddress": {
          "id": "/subscriptions/subid/resourceGroups/rg2/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/pip2"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "/subscriptions/subid/resourceGroups/rg2/providers/Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/lb2/frontendIPConfigurations/lbfe2",
      "properties": {
        "publicIPAddress": {
          "id": "/subscriptions/subid/resourceGroups/rg1/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/pip1"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I would probably still prefer a blue/green solution that does not depend on something like this, but it can be a start.